# "Ряд предпринимателей не одобрил(и)..."

Tags: согласование

Подобные вопросы тут уже были, но, пожалуйста, помогите мне с этим конкретным случаем. Я написал "Ряд предпринимателей не одобрили...", а потом засомневался. Может, надо было написать "не одобрил"?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеете право написать именно так, Розенталь поясняет:
http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm.

Сказуемое ставится как в форме ед., так и в форме множ. числа, если собирательное существительное имеет при себе управляемое слово в родительном падеже множественного числа.Предпочтительно множ. число в след. случаях:...5) если подчеркивается активность и раздельность действия каждого действующего лица, например: Ряд сотрудников отдела заявили, что они не согласны с позицией администрации; но: Ряд вопросов, стоявших на повестке дня, за недостатком времени не обсуждался (подлежащее обозначает неодушевленный предмет). Сказуемое в страдательном обороте обычно ставится в ед. числе, так как подлежащее обозначает объект действия, а не его субъект, например: Большинство участников соревнований размещено в пансионатах; Ряд молодых бизнесменов направлен за рубеж;

Ряд предпринимателей не одобрили.- всё верно, подчёркивается, что каждый  предприниматель из входящих в этот ряд,не одобрил, активное действие, поэтому сказуемое во множ.числе: не ряд одобрил, а каждый из них.

В последнее время явно наметилась тенденция к согласованию по смыслу, а не по грамматике.